# send table row to next page

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to make a simpel webshop where I list some items (to order) on each row there is a form field for tell how many the costumer wants of the item. Then she submit a button and the action is another page where the item will be added to an MYSQL table to be processed later Im thinkking that when user hit the submit there is a hidden field that send the itemid.

I need to get a way to make the itemid with me to the other side but I cant make the variable specific for the row. the ArtikelNR variable $row["ArtikelNr"] shoudld be assigned to the hidden form and be accessable on next page as ArtikelNr = $_REQUEST['ArtikelNr']; and it works so far but it always the laast item number not the itemnumber that i specific for the choosen row. How do I make $form4 = ' '; row speciific so i can catch it on next page and add it to the basket.

```
<?php include 'databas_connect.inc'; ?>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT `ArtikelNr`, `ArtikelNamn`, `Storlek`, `ArtikelPris`,  
 `artikelbild`FROM `artiklar` ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0)
{
    echo "<table><tr><th>Antal</th><th>ArtikelNr</th><th> ArtikelNamn</th>
<th>Storlek</th><th>ArtikelPris</th><th>Artikelbild</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $number =1;
        $artnr  = $row["ArtikelNr"];
        $prefix = "pre_";
        $sufix = 1;
        ${$prefix .$sufix} =$row["ArtikelNr"] ;
        $form1 = '<form action="sida61.php" method="post">';
        $form2 = '<label for="antal"></label>';
        $form3 = '<input type="text" name="antal" size="2" maxlength="2"value="1" id="antal">';
        $form4 = '<input type="hidden" name="ArtikelNr" value="'.${$prefix .$sufix}.'"/> ';
        $form5 = '<input type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="KÖP" />';
        $form6 = '</form>';
        $form = $form1 . $form2 . $form3 . $form4 . $form5 ;
        $img =  "<img src=./img/>";
        $image=$row['artikelbild'];
        $path ="<img src='./img/".$image."' />";

        echo "<tr><td>" .$form. "</td><td>" . $row["ArtikelNr"]. "</td><td>" . 
        $row["ArtikelNamn"]. " </td><td> " . $row["Storlek"]. " </td><td>" . 
        $row["ArtikelPris"].  " </td><td>".$path."</td></tr>";
        ++$sufix;
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}     
$conn->close();
?>
```

here is code for sida61.php

```
<?php include 'databas_connect.inc'; ?>
<?php
    session_start();
    $ArtikelNr = $_REQUEST['ArtikelNr'];
    $antal     = $_REQUEST['antal'];
    //$KundNr  = $_SESSION["Kund"];
    // attempt insert query execution
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `kundkorg`( `ArtikelNr`, `antal`, `KundNr`) 
                  VALUES (1,$antal, 2)";
    if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
        print_r($_REQUEST);  // I just do this to se value of $_REQUEST it is always 8 since I have 8 items i dont know why
    } 
    else
    {
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . 
        mysqli_error($conn);
    }
    // close connection
    mysqli_close($conn);
    //header("Location: 6.php");
?>
```

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Give your `<form>` a unique `id`, like the `ArtikelNr`...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto How would that help? That's only useful for client-side manipulation. Makes no difference to what gets submitted back.

Comment: Do you want to pass `$row["ArtikelNr"]` only or shoudl it include the `$prefix` and `$suffix`

Comment: `${$prefix .$sufix}` what is this syntax? not seen that before, excuse my ignorance. What does it output in the $form4 row? what's wrong with `<input type="hidden" name="ArtikelNr" value="'.$row["ArtikelNr"].'"/>` if that's what you want to send back?

Comment: Nope, if every `<form>` has its id, those are separated forms. Now they are the same form., and all values are submitted. Try watching the submitted values in your browser. (Type `F12` in Edge, FF...)

Comment: `${$var}` and `$$var` is valid syntax in PHP, and means a variable that has the name of the value of `$var`... However, i did not see it with expressions, like `${$prefix . $suffix}`, before...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto https://jsfiddle.net/6buus8fk/ can't reproduce your assertion about the form at all. If i submit the first form in the fiddle and watch the request, b = 1, as it should. If I submit the second form, b = 2, as it should.

Comment: Yes I want to pass $row["ArtikelNr"] acxtually but when I used that directly to assign it to '<input type="hidden" name="ArtikelNr" value="'. $row["ArtikelNr"].'"/> it workds but ArtikelNt is always the last item in the rows. eg if I hsave ten items it has the itemifd of row 10 even if I choose row 3.

Comment: Give your <form> a unique id, like the ArtikelNr... – Usagi Miyamoto - How will I submit two forms with one button?

Comment: thanks @ RiggsFolly Im a newbie I will fix  the code. im just doing my first site. so im haooy you give me this tips.

Comment: @JohanMartens can you show a bit of the code where you are receiving the submission of the form and reading the article no? (i.e code from sida61.php)? Maybe something there is not interpreting it. On the face of it, there's no reason why it shouldn't submit the correct values.

Comment: @JYoThI we just showed you this isn't relevant, and you deleted your answer. Why are you peddling it as a comment now as well? It still doesn't apply to this situation, because the form is a child of the **td** as is clearly shown by the code, and there's nothing wrong with doing that.

Comment: He missed to concatenate form close tag $form6 = '</form>';
        $form = $form1 . $form2 . $form3 . $form4 . $form5 ;

Comment: @ADyson            <?php
                          session_start();
   $ArtikelNr = $_REQUEST['ArtikelNr'];
   $antal     = $_REQUEST['antal'];
   $sql = "INSERT INTO `kundkorg`( `ArtikelNr`, `antal`, 
                       `KundNr`) VALUES (1,$antal, 2)";
   if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
    {
    print_r($_REQUEST);
    } 
    else
    {
     echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. 
                                " . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
    // close connection
          mysqli_close($conn);
          //header("Location: 6.php");
                        ?>

Comment: sorry Im new here I dont k now how to format in the comments

Comment: You cannot, so we discourage using comment for code. But you can edit your question and add extra information into that

Comment: @JYoThI why didn't you point that out before then, instead of just a vague assertion. It's the kind of detail which is easily missed, and well done for spotting it. Less well done for not actually mentioning it until the last moment!

Comment: @JohanMartens your INSERT statement in sida61.php is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Once you've fixed the issue in this question, you should research how to use prepared statements and parameters to protect your data against malicious input which could steal, corrupt or destroy your data. Have a look at http://bobby-tables.com/ as a starter

Comment: You should not work on any webshop functionality as long as you still write SQL queries that leave you wide open to SQL injection ...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you were attempting to add a prefix and a suffix as you say you want to pass just the `$row["ArtikelNr"]` in your hidden field.

You also missed concatenating your `</form>` closing tag into your `$form` variable.

So this code should achieve what you want.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $form .= '<form action="sida61.php" method="post">';
    $form .= '<label for="antal"></label>';
    $form .= '<input type="text" name="antal" size="2" maxlength="2"value="1" id="antal">';

    $form .= "<input type='hidden' name='ArtikelNr' value='{$row['ArtikelNr']}'/>";
    $form .= '<input type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="KÖP" />';
    $form .= '</form>';

    $img =  "<img src='./img/{$row['artikelbild']}'/>";

    echo "<tr><td>$form</td><td>{$row['ArtikelNr']}</td><td>
            {$row['ArtikelNamn']}</td><td>{$row['Storlek']}</td><td>
            {$row['ArtikelPris']</td><td>$path</td></tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes I se now I missed to missed concatenating your  closing tag into  $form variable. the correct code is

```
$form1 = '<form action="sida61.php"  method="post">';
$form2 = '<label for="antal"></label>';
$form3 = '<input type="text" name="antal" size="2" maxlength="2"value="1" 
 id="antal">';
$form4 = '<input type="hidden" name="ArtikelNr" value="'. 
 $row["ArtikelNr"].'"/> ';
$form5 = '<input type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="KÖP" />';
$form6 = '</form>';
$form = $form1 . $form2 . $form3 . $form4 . $form5 . $form6 ;
```

Thanks so much @RiggsFolly

When I tried your code it added a new form on each row making me have 9 input fields on row 9. but You helped me anyway!!